# Java jar file is available in docker image but unable to access

Tags: docker, dockerfile

While runnig the docker image I for a spring boot app I am getting jar file not accessible screen shot attached .I have tried every thing I know but nothing works.Please help

my docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:14-jdk-alpine
MAINTAINER admin
ADD ./target/service-registry.jar /opt/app/service-registry.jar
WORKDIR /opt/app
ENV PATH="${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin"
EXPOSE 8761
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "/opt/app/service-registry.jar "]
```

[image: While running docker run command getting the unable to access jar file]

Comment: Errors should be given as text, not screenshots. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: That said, the space between the `.jar` and the `"` is a problem. You may have a file named `/opt/app/service-registry.jar`, but you probably don't have a file with the same name but with a space on the end of it.

Comment: OMG thank u so much I have been struggling from last 4 hrs on the issue seems like space was the culprit